# Display text according to the selected option

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an option for users to select if 'Yes' or 'No'. If options selected values 'y' text box 'adv1' displays 750. If else it is 0.00

```
   <table>

         <tr>
           <td>Advance Required</td>
           <td><select name="advReq" id="ad">
               <option value="y">Yes</option>
               <option value="n">No</option>
               </select>
           </td>
           <td><input name="adv1" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="" /></td>
       </tr>

   </table>
```

Comment: PHP won't unless you rerender the page but you can use javascript to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
     function updateText(val) {
      var $el = document.getElementById("adv1");
      if(val == 'y'){
       $el.value = "$ 750";
      } else {
       $el.value = "0";
      }
     }
    </script>

<select name="advReq" id="ad" onchange="updateText(this.value)">
      <option value="y">Yes</option>
      <option value="n">No</option>
</select>
<input name="adv1" type="text" id="adv1"  value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a simple JavaScript.

HTML Markup :

```
<select name="advReq" id="ad" onchange="changeValue(this.value)">
      <option value="y">Yes</option>
      <option value="n">No</option>
</select>
<input name="adv1" type="text" id="adv"  value="" />
```

JavaScript :

```
function changeValue(val){
//use comparison operator   
if(val=="y")
     document.getElementById('adv').value = "$ 750";
   else
     document.getElementById('adv').value = "0.00";
}
```

If you wish to change the value dynamically with values from Server at real time. You can do it by using AJAX calls.

Comment: Sriraman, its working not with value, but with value change. Eg: If I change 'Yes' to 'No' the text displays '$750'. Also it is not reverted on changing again to 'Yes'

Comment: You can do this easily using jquery.